# How can I block users from registering with disposable email addresses?

Tags: 7, forms, users, emails

I have a site where users send messages to one another using the Private Message module, and they are notified of messages by email.

On this site, there are a variety of spammers, scammers, and abusive users who attempt to register multiple accounts using disposable email addresses.

I know it's impossible to block every possible disposable email address domain, but is there anything in the Drupal world that can help me?

- I considered white-listing valid domains, but my user base is too diverse for this.
- The only project I could find on drupal.org [has been abandoned](https://www.drupal.org/project/undisposable).
- There are third-party APIs such as [this one](http://www.block-disposable-email.com/cms/).

**At the moment, I'm blocking them manually using this code:**

```
/**
 * Custom validation function from the Domain Registration module (1.0).
 *
 * Checks if the domain in the email address is on a list of blocked domains.
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 */

function MYMODULE_domain_registration_user_register_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $default_message = t('You are not allowed to register for an account on this site.  Contact support for more information.');
  $mail = explode('@', $form_state['values']['mail']);
  $exact_domains = array(
    'ad.drupaler.org',
    'drupaler.org',
  );
  $partial_domains = array(
    'pp.ua',
    'guerrilamail',
  );
  if (isset($mail[1]) && !empty($exact_domains)) {
    if (in_array($mail[1], $exact_domains) || MYMODULE_contactinfo_check_banned_words($mail[1], $partial_domains)) {
      form_set_error('account', variable_get('domain_registration_message', $default_message));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use a [ReCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) in you registration form, if you aren't already, to get rid off all the robot/spider/automated spam registrations.

Comment: @NoSssweat Alas, in my case, the problem is manually registered spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mentioned it is impossible to block all disposable domains.

If you want to end the madness, the most effective solution would be: Upon registration you send a confirmation link or code to a mobile phone number

Take a look at:

1. [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) module
2. [VoIP Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/voipdrupal) module

Using [Unique field](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) you could make sure that the phone number can only be used once.

Checkout: [How to send SMS messages (Drupal Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqkOcz_8I4U)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good ( but I think sms verification is better solution),any way I improved your solution with integrate it with `block-disposable-emai`,have [simple JSON BASE APIs](http://www.block-disposable-email.com/cms/help-and-usage/json-based-api/)

```
   /**
 * Custom validation function from the Domain Registration module (1.0).
 *
 * Checks if the domain in the email address is on a list of blocked domains.
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 */

function MYMODULE_domain_registration_user_register_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $default_message = t('You are not allowed to register for an account on this site.  Contact support for more information.');
  $mail = explode('@', $form_state['values']['mail']);
  $exact_domains = array(
    'ad.drupaler.org',
    'drupaler.org',
  );
  $partial_domains = array(
    'pp.ua',
    'guerrilamail',
  );

  $key     = '12345abcapikey'; //please get your own valid api key
  $request = 'http://check.block-disposable-email.com/api/json/'.$key.'/'.$mail[1]; 
  if (isset($mail[1])) {
  $response = file_get_contents($request);
  $dea = json_decode($response);
  if ($dea->request_status == 'success'){
    if ($dea->domain_status == 'block' && $dea->domain_type == 'dea_provider' && $dea->domain_is_handpicked == 1){
    // deny registration ...
              form_set_error('account', variable_get('domain_registration_message', $default_message));

    }

  }else{
    form_set_error('account', "try again");
   }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problems so I create a Free API service that recognize disposable and temporary email address: [Block Temporary Email](https://block-temporary-email.com)

Email Endpoint:

`GET` `https://block-temporary-email.com/check/email/example@simplemail.top`

JSON response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "domain": "simplemail.top",
  "temporary": true,
  "dns": true,
}
```

This API is 100% free and have no limits.

This site provides a free and updated TXT list of disposable email providers too.

**Disclaimer: I made this API**